# Find which of the dependencies triggered useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

```
const OAuthButtons: React.FC<OAuthButtonsProps> = () => {
  const [signInWithGoogle, userCred1, loading, error] = useSignInWithGoogle(auth);
  const [signInWithGithub, userCred2, loading1, error1] = useSignInWithGithub(auth);

  const createUserDocument = async (user: User) => {
    const userDocRef = doc(firestore, "users", user.uid);
    await setDoc(userDocRef,JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));

  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // if (userCred1) {
    //   createUserDocument(userCred1.user);
    // }
  }, [userCred1,userCred2]);
```

I am trying the save the authenticated users in my database.Is it it possible to find which of the dependencies changed in useeffect hook. So accordingly I can check if that user exists and save in my database.

I want to save the users whenever a user logs in with Google or Github.

Answer (score 1):

Just create two seperate use effect, this way each user will trigger it's own use effect and it will remove the overhead of trying to find out which one is triggered the single use effect

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (userCred1) {
       createUserDocument(userCred1.user);
    }
  }, [userCred1]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (userCred2) {
       createUserDocument(userCred2.user);
    }
  }, [userCred2]);
```